# Checkbox как хранить в БД?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть поле exlusive , оно хранит одно значение true или false. Какой тип данных присвоить в БД , и как в модели с ним работать ??
Вот такой код формирует чекбокс

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'exclusive')->checkbox() ?>
```

Comment: Например `tinyint(1)`, где храните 0 или 1 в зависимости от `true` - `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MySQL есть специальный тип данных - BOOLEAN. По сути, он является псевдонимом типа  TINYINT(1). При обработке запроса, значение true или false будет преобразовано в 1 или 0. Так же, можно использовать просто тип данных TINYINT(1).